# surprise on switching branches

Tags: git, branch

Is true that i'm novice when is about to use git, but I hope I didn't loose too much of my work. I've tryed to switch to the master branch, but as you can see without success.

```
Alx@I5-PC /d/workspace/android/tutorialA2 (about_screen)
$ git st
# On branch about_screen
nothing to commit (working directory clean)

Alx@I5-PC /d/workspace/android/tutorialA2 (about_screen)
$ git br
master
* about_screen

Alx@I5-PC /d/workspace/android/tutorialA2 (about_screen)
$ git co master
Unlink of file 'res/layout/view_about.xml' failed. Should I try again? (y/n) y
Unlink of file 'res/layout/view_about.xml' failed. Should I try again? (y/n) err
or: unable to unlink old 'res/layout/view_about.xml' (Permission denied)
```

Now, when I wish to make a checkout to the last stable commit, I get this message:

```
 $ git co 8759ba
 fatal: Unable to create 'd:/workspace/android/tutorialA2/.git/index.lock': File exists.

 If no other git process is currently running, this probably means a
 git process crashed in this repository earlier. Make sure no other git
 process is running and remove the file manually to continue.
```

Comment: `ls -l res/layout/view_about.xml`

Comment: @Tass: I have that file. The problem is that I've lost some files and versions. Git says that I've modified and deleted some files, but I didn't. How can I revert to the previus stable version, the one from the last git status

Comment: Does another process have that file open?  If you're unsure, try checking it out after a reboot.

Comment: I think the error message you added is fairly straight forward.  If you don't have another git process open, manually delete the lock file

Comment: @doledoug that's not the question, I'd like the full output of that command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to have two problems.

1. You have a permissions issue with res/layout/view_about.xml.  You should examine and correct the permissions for that file.
2. Git has a lockfile in place.  If no other git processes are running, remove the lock file as stated in the error message.

Once you do these two things, you should get back into a state where you can switch branches freely.

Once you can do that, you can reset a branch to previous commit, with "git reset --hard <sha1>" where <sha1> is the ID of the commit to which you want to return.  Note that this command is destructive - it will do what you tell it and make your working directory look like the state it was at the time of that commit.  Be sure it's the one you want before you do it.  There are ways to recover if you get it wrong, but it's better not to get it wrong.